# What to do when Strong Customer Authentication fails?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to implement a [Subscription signup and payment flow](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#handling-action-required) with **Stripe.js V3** and **Strong Customer Authentication (SCA)** like this:

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_9hA8gecxBFTY3O6kUm7hl16j');

var paymentIntentSecret = 'pi_91_secret_W9';

stripe.handleCardPayment(
    paymentIntentSecret
).then(function (result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Display error.message in your UI.
    } else {
        // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.
    }
})
```

Everything works great when the payment **succeeds**.

But what am I supposed to do when it **fails**?

Should I redirect the user to the initial payment screen, so s/he can start over?

When I do that I get this error:

> You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it has a status of canceled. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be confirmed: requires_confirmation, requires_action.

Or should I delete everything, including the previously created `stripe_customer` and `stripe_subscription`, and then start over?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Most people would show something like display "Payment failed, please verify input" and redirect to the input form. But you can of course just shoot them dead, why not. Worst thing to happen is an angry customer that doesn't come back. Transactions _usually_ don't fail for no reason.

Comment: @Damon: OK, but at that point the input has already been made and processed by Stripe. So how can the input be verified here?

Comment: Does not need to be. You don't need to, and indeed _shouldn't_ verify it at all, except maybe for totally obvious errors such as an empty field. The transaction succeeds or it fails (not your problem!). All you do is provide the form and a website that says either "Success" or "Fail". If you _think_ it's good after verifying on your server, but the transaction fails, it has still failed, you will not get to see money. There is just black and white, no grey.

Answer (score 1):

If the payment fails entirely(maybe it was declined, or 3D Secure was attempted but not completed successfully) , the PaymentIntent from the first invoice should be in the `requires_payment_method` state and the subscription is `incomplete`.

You can choose to attempt to collect new payment information from the user and use that to complete the invoice payment and activate the subscription. You can re-use the same PaymentIntent throughout this and try as many times as you wish. For example, if you had a payment form with a Card Element for collecting details, you can have the user enter a new card and call this again :

```
stripe.handleCardPayment(cardElement,
    paymentIntentSecret
).then(function(res){...})
```

Alternatively you can choose to cancel the subscription entirely if you wish. Otherwise if you do nothing, or the customer isn't able to provide a payment method that works, after 24 hours, Stripe effectively cancels the subscription for you.

Your error message seems to indicate the PaymentIntent was cancelled, which might mean you cancelled the subscription, or you're trying this more than 24 hours after the initial payment, I'm not sure.

This link goes into more detail: 
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/lifecycle#incomplete